# Log table with non unique columns; what indexes to create

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, t-sql, indexing

I have a log table with two columns.

1. DocumentType (varchar(250), not unique, not null)
2. DateEntered  (Date, not unique, not null)

The table will only have rows inserted, never updated or deleted.

Here is the stored procedure for the report:

```
SELECT DocumentType, 
       COUNT(DocumentType) AS "CountOfDocs"
FROM DocumentTypes
WHERE DateEntered>= @StartDate AND DateEntered<= @EndDate
GROUP BY DocumentType
ORDER BY DocumentType ASC;
```

In the future user may want to also filter by document type in a different report. I currently have a non-clustered index containing both columns. Is this the proper index to create?

Comment: I am guessing DocumentType is not unique, correct?

Comment: What is the expected rate of insertions to this table?

Comment: correct nothing is unique. Anywhere from 100 to 1000 per business day, through a sql job schedule once per.

Comment: Also as of now I have a non-clustered index as edited on the main question as well.

Answer (score 1):

Clustered index on the date, for sure.

I think your NCI is fine.  I would say both in as named columns as I assume you will have the date in the `WHERE` clause for your queries.  I don't think 1000 per day worst case scenario will have a major impact on insert times when loading the data.

Comment: Well I can't do Clustered Index on the the date, b/c the date may not be unique, as I can have multiple insertions on one date. Happy though it seems the NCI I created seems like a good idea to you.

Comment: Good.  Also, you can clustered on the date.  The clustered index does not have to follow a primary key.   The clustered index is a physical structure, the PK a logical constraint to prevent duplicates.

Comment: true, but if I create a clustered index that is not unique SQL Server will add a "uniquefier" (a 4-byte INT) to those rows that aren't unique, and I believe that's suppose to be bad practice, hence why you usually do a NCI for non-unique data.

Comment: Usually, however you have a date column here and presumably you will querying on date ranges from time to time (i.e. all individual entries between certain dates and not grouped up), in which case you can see some benefit.  Up to you.

Comment: Although the NCI has two columns, if I query with one column or two columns in my where clause, I believe the performance will be the same, as opposed to having two different indexes correct? As of now the report only queries us date as the predicate but I'm just thinking ahead, which I why I put both columns in the NCI.

Comment: If your NCI is `(DocumentType, DateEntered ASC)` then in that leaf you have them out of date order.  In a query where you want the granular or simple aggregation level data between two date ranges without regard to the order of the `DocumentType`, the clustered index will be faster (e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE EnteredDate BETWEEN xxxx AND xxxx`).  If you order by as per your NCI at the granular, the NCI will have the greatest impact.  I don't know your extra query requirements but I don't think you have a lot to lose from the clustered index (but perhaps not a lot to gain too).

Comment: Well in my query I have a order by DocumentType, the NCI I have is DateEntered, and DocumentType, both say Sort Order Ascending. Now you are saying I should take that and make it clustered?

Answer (score 1):

Don't add any index. It'll be heap table and wait for your "future you" with task to select something from this table :).

If you want index:

1. With heap: Add index on field you will filter and if the second one is only in select (=isn't in where clause) put the second one as included column. If you'll filter with both column put index on both columns.
2. If you want add clustered index (for example on new autoincrement primary key column) add only one index on col you want filter or try to don't add aditional index and check execution plan and efectivity - in most cases is clustered index with seeks enough.

Don't create clustered index on nonunique columns (it's used only in very special cases).

Comment: So you suggest creating 2 non-clustered indexes, this will cover a query based on only one column and\or both columns?

Comment: Great - you added qry - so index on DateEntered and include DocumentType.

Comment: Can you be more specific, are you saying created a clustered index with both columns? I found when I created two non-clustered indexes the query did a table scan, with one non-clustered index containing both columns it did an Index Seek.

Comment: Sorry - into clustered index you cannot include columns - so i thought non-clustered. create nonclustered index IX_DateEntered on DocumentTypes (DateEntered) include (DocumentType)